# Problem in making http.get() request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, get

I am learning about API's and http request in flutter and I am facing problem in making a get request as in any tutorial they are directly pasting string URL inside get as parameter but when I post it as string it is showing error:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

Can anyone help me in this?
This is my sample code :

```dart
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  // This example uses the Google Books API to search for books about http.
  // https://developers.google.com/books/docs/overview
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={http}';

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var response = await http.get(url); // i am getting error here
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
    print('Number of books about http: $itemCount.');
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
}
```

Here is image of my code with error:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this i had to change the funtion name main(List<String> arguments)  to just test() and call the test function on a button or add in initState,@Ravinderraj singh

Answer (score 17):

First, add the http library to your project:

```
flutter pub add http
```

Then import http as http:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Then parse your link to Uri using:

```
var url = Uri.parse('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={http}');
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
try {
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String data = response.body;
    var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
    return decodedData;
  } else {
    return 'failed';
  }
} catch (e) {
  return 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If still doesn't work try this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

var response = get(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (Add http to pubspec.yaml under dependencies):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var response = http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You passing string the error says need an uri so create an uri and use in it.

```
var uri = new Uri.http("example.org", "/path", { "q" : "{http}" });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your pubspec.yaml file and HTTP version. It should be the actual one you can find here: https://pub.dev/packages/http/install
For example, it is:

```
http: ^0.12.2
```

at the moment

Here is my code and it works well:

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackowerflow/my_app.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

> my_app.dart

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> stackHelp() async {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={http}';

    // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
      print('Number of books about http: $itemCount.');
    } else {
      print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView '),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: TextButton(onPressed: stackHelp, child: Text('Push me')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> RESULT

```
flutter: Number of books about http: 485.
```